# "Too much recursion" when creating LatLng a different way

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just want to ask some help about the error to much recursion. If I have this kind of code

in my ajax request

```
var arr=["10.296954, 123.896785","10.298750, 123.895974",
         "10.299524, 123.898862","10.294086, 123.897424"];

$.ajax({
    ....
    ... 
    ....
    success:function(data){
       for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng((arr[i]));
     }
   }

 });
```

but if I change something like this

```
var arr=["10.296954, 123.896785","10.298750, 123.895974",
         "10.299524, 123.898862","10.294086, 123.897424"];

$.ajax({
    ....
    ... 
    ....
    success:function(data){
       for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                       path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(10.296954, 123.896785),
                                 new google.maps.LatLng(10.298750, 123.895974),
                                 new google.maps.LatLng(10.299524, 123.898862),
                                 new google.maps.LatLng(10.294086, 123.897424));


                   }
   }

 });
```

It works properly it will draw polylines in the map

Can you help me on this?. what is the wrong of my code if I will loop the coordinates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Api v3 - map.panTo causing "too much recursion"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881114/google-maps-api-v3-map-panto-causing-too-much-recursion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you need to pass separate `lats` and `longs` to the `path`.
Try changing your array into a finer grained model, e.g.:

```
var arr=[{lat: 10.296954, lng: 123.896785},
         {lat: 10.298750, lng: 123.895974},
         {lat: 10.299524, lng: 123.898862},
         {lat: 10.294086, lng: 123.897424}];
```

and then change:

```
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i].lat, arr[i].lng);
```

Comment: your post is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

[`LatLng` takes *two numeric arguments* for the coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLng), but only one - a *string*, e.g. "10.296954, 123.896785", which is an invalid value for the constructor - is supplied. It's a shame the error isn't more helpful, but that's the cause.

While the source data *can* be changed, and doing so might be arguably better overall, consider the use of a helper "factory" function as an alternative.

```
// Create a LatLng given coordinates from a string
// in the form of "lat, lng" or an array of [lat, lng].
function mkLatLng (coords) {
    var parts = ("" + coords).split(/,\s+/);       
    var lat = parseFloat(parts[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(parts[1]);
    if (parts.length != 2 || isNaN(lat) || isNaN(lng)) {
        throw "invalid data";
    }
    // Now passing in TWO NUMERIC ARGUMENTS, as per the API
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}
```

Then it can be used as a proxy to correctly coerce/convert the data.

```
 path.push(mkLatLng(arr[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2){// increment i by 2
   path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i],arr[i+1]); // now you get lat,long
}
```

Your array should be, in the above case,

```
var arr=[10.296954, 123.896785,10.298750, 123.895974,
         10.299524, 123.898862,10.294086, 123.897424];
```

Otherwise, try the below code,

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   var latlng=arr[i].replace('"','').split(',');
   path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0],latlng[1]);
}
```

Comment: This won't work (with the data in the post) because the array values are like `"10.296954, 123.896785"`. They must first be converted to separate lat/long numbers.

Comment: simply .split() by ", " and then parseFloat() each part (one can't always choose how the input should look like)... parseFloat() is always suggested.